# Is there any "ember-moment-shim" alternative for dayJS?

Tags: ember.js, locale, shim, ember-addon, dayjs

`ember-moment-shim` is an ember addon that generates the locales conditionally based on **Moment.js** and **Moment-Timezone**.

Any tools or processes to accomplish the same with just DayJs instead.

Ref: https://github.com/jasonmit/ember-cli-moment-shim

**UPDATE**:

I want to lazy load or dynamically load the dayJs locales based on the requirement. And every time you need to load a locale, you need to import it like

`import fr from 'dayjs/locale/fr'`

just that it would be a different locale every time and could change on refresh based on the settings from API response.

`ember-auto-import` throws following **Error**

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module*
```

Comment: Have you tried just to use `ember-auto-import`?

Comment: Yes, it throws Uncaught Error. Updated the question accordingly

Comment: Please add the code that surrounds `import fr from 'dayjs/locale/fr'`. Where are you running that? How do you get `based on the settings from API response. `. Also have you followed the instructions to use Dynamic imports: https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import#dynamic-import

Answer (score 1):

Addons like ember-cli-moment-shim are no longer required to use libraries from NPM instead you can use them directly after installing `ember-auto-import`.

From the command line do:

```sh
ember install ember-auto-import
npm install dayjs
```

Then you can just import dayjs where you need it.

For example in a component:

```
//app/components/today.js
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class TodayComponent extends Component {
  today = dayjs().format();
}
```

Comment: It is already been used. And seems to be not working for my case. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: What is the browser support for dynamic-imports? To be even specific, does it support Browsers >= IE11 ?

Comment: One of the great things about `ember-auto-import` is that it converts the dynamic import into working code on all the browsers in your `config/targets.js` file. The dynamic imports get transpiled out so that they work in everything your app supports.